# Display when key is pressed in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

There is a program which takes live feed from camera: I want to perform some operations when a key from keyboard is pressed without disturbing the on going process. I tried

```
if(waitKey(30) == '27')
  cout << "ESC pressed";
```

But this one doesn't work.

Comment: Do You have this in a loop?

Comment: what do you mean by "without disturbing the on going process"? Do you want/try to catch the keyPress in a separate thread?

Comment: I want to catch the key press in the same thread only. And yeah it is in a loop

Answer (score 3):

> [Documentation:](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey)
>   The function only works if there is at least one HighGUI window created and the window is active. If there are several HighGUI windows, any of them can be active.

As I understand from your question, It seems that you don't have any active windows. If that is the case, first show up an image with the help of `imshow` function and then wait for any key to be pressed.

Comment: I think you might also have to click in the shown window.

Answer (score 3):

`cv::waitKey()` returns an integer. You can either convert it to a `char` and then compare to the decimal ASCII code of any key like this

```
if((char)cv::waitKey(1) == 27) std::cout << "ESC pressed" << std::endl;
```

or (equivalently) write

```
if(cv::waitKey(1) % 256 == 27) std::cout << "ESC pressed" << std::endl;
```